# Using individual script files and rails assets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My app uses the old version of jquery, and I wanted to do a POC inside my app using the new jquery version to show some of the benefits and at the same time rewrite some of the back-end.

So what I did was that I added a layout to my controller named `poc`, and I removed the application javascript tag from the poc layout. But I left the this inside `poc` layout:

```
= yield :footer_js
```

So that I can load javascript on the individual page, which I did like this :

```
- content_for :footer_js do
  = javascript_include_tag 'new_jquery'
```

And on my new page only jquery loads up, which I added to `app/assets/javascript/poc/new_jquery.js` and it all works perfectly well on my local machine (development environment).

However once I deploy it to production it's a different story, nothing is loading up. My scripts are located at `app/assets/javascript/poc` and under this there is `new_jquery.js` itself.

And then there are files under the `app/assets/javascript/poc/services` and `app/assets/javascript/validations` which I individually load on view.

**Question:**
Am I doing this the right way? And if yes, how do I get these file to work in production with assets pipeline? Or if I'm doing it the wrong way, what's the right way to test an isolated page with isolated dependencies in production?

Comment: Have you tried `javascript_include_tag 'poc/new_jquery'`?

Comment: It already works on localhost when I use the `new_jquery` I'm pretty sure that won't have any effect on compilation, but I ll give it a shot. Any reasons behind suggesting that?

Comment: Yes, if it works on localhost this makes little sense, I'm just hitting the bush to see if something pops up. I'd actually bet for a pre-compilation issue on production (file not precompiled, not found due to some missconfiguration on `production.rb` or such). Have you compiled assets locally with `rake assets:precompile`? It not, can you try? Also, are you getting a 404 on your browser when you load the production site, for that particular js file?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was as described in the answer I end up using the new layout, however instead of individually including the javascript files on the view, I added a `poc.js` in the `app/assets/javascript` next to the `application.js`, and referenced all the js files I needed from `poc.js` and included `poc.js` in the layout.

Also I added `poc.js` in the application.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'poc.js']
```

Worked great!